# undefined index $_POST PHP_SELF

Tags: php

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php print $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    <p><input type="text" name = "word"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
    <?php 
    $i = $_POST['word'];
        echo strrev($i);
    ?>
```

gives me this error:
Notice: Undefined index: word in C:\wamp\www\php\reverse.php on line 6
is there a solution?

Comment: its telling you that `$_POST['word']` doest exist. Should it always, or is it optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['word']` is not defined so use [**isset**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php print $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    <p><input type="text" name = "word"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['word']))
    {
      $i = $_POST['word'];
        echo strrev($i);
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this error as followed:

```
if(isset($_POST['world'])){

    echo strrev($_POST['world']);

}
```

If `$_POST['world']` doesn't exist the code wont be run